# Understanding wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, scjp

I created this silly program to play with `wait()`

```
public class WaitTest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

      System.out.print("1 ");
      synchronized(args){

        System.out.print("2 ");

        try {
          args.wait();
          args.notifyAll();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){ System.out.print("exception caught");}

        System.out.print("3 ");
      }
   }
}
```

On my machine, the code never gets to print 3, unless I write `wait(100)` or another number of milliseconds. Why is this?

Comment: Could you possibly try reading at least half an hour about a certain concept before asking yet another question?

Comment: That's a very interesting suggestion, thanks. You've been most helpful.

Comment: well, I have been helpful, providing you with an answer. Now in return you should take my comments seriously ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing the wait() before the notifyAll().  wait() is going to block.  When you put the timeout value in, wait() will timeout and then your program will continue.  If you want your program to work, create a thread and do your notifyAll() there.  wait() and notifyAll are designed for interthread synchronization.

Answer (score 6):

`wait` and `notifyAll` are for multithreading.  `args.wait()` will wait **forever** until some other thread calls `args.notifyAll()` or `args.notify()`.

When you call `args.wait(100)`, it is waiting for 100ms, timing out, and continuing.

If you are familiar with semaphores, that is basically what wait/notify are.

Answer (score 5):

You only have one thread. wait() is waiting for a notify from another thread.

Answer (score 3):

Since no other thread notifies the object's monitor you are waiting on, it is just blocking there. And since you are synchronizing and waiting on a local variable, hardly any other thread would be able to call `notify()` on it.

Comment: Thanks, this has saved me time (and provided content for others to learn). Nice going, man.

Answer (score 1):

From http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

> When wait is invoked, the thread
>   releases the lock and suspends
>   execution. At some future time,
>   *another* thread will acquire the same
>   lock and invoke Object.notifyAll,
>   informing all threads waiting on that
>   lock that something important has
>   happened:

The Java Tutorial is an excellent learning resource.